# The speed of light and fields

Tags: speed-of-light, field-theory

Does the speed of light apply to the speed of (waves?) in every known field, or does it only apply to the electromagnetic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It applies to everything in the sense that it imposes an upper limit i.e. no field can propagate faster than the speed of light. A massive field obviously won't propagate at the speed of light, but massless fields do propagate at the speed of light (provided other effects don't slow them).

However there is a complication you should be aware of in that we define two velocities for wave motion, the [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) and the [phase velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity). The phase velocity can exceed the speed of light but it can't carry any information. The group velocity cannot exceed the speed of light. In the QM context the group velocity corresponds to the particle velocity.